# NSSortDescriptor sorting using NSDate in Swift

Tags: swift, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

How would I sort a NSFetchRequest with that the date property of the managed object. So that it creates a array with the dates going in order?

Here is my code so far...

```
    var request : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "History");
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "counts = %@", true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [???] <- What should I put here?
    var results : [NSManagedObject] = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as [NSManagedObject]
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
// newest first
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)]
```

*NB: You do not need* `: [NSManagedObject]` *if you already have* `as [NSManagedObject]`.
*You do not need* `: NSFetchRequest` *when you use the factory method of* `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: I see those NBs, but I am just so used to having the type nearby identifier declaration. I'm sure I'll get used to it.